# Nginx: How to prevent caching ajax requests on proxy?

Tags: nginx

I currently need to avoid caching Ajax requests, but to keep caching the result pages.

I know which directives disallow caching:
proxy_no_cache or proxy_cache_bypass
But how to add a proper statement. Via if block?
The statement should be like this?

```
$http_x_requested_with=XMLHttpRequest
```

Thanks ;)

**Update**

Like that?

```
proxy_cache_bypass  $http_x_requested_with=XMLHttpRequest;
proxy_no_cache      $http_x_requested_with=XMLHttpRequest;
```

Answer (score 6):

Using if block inside a location block could be tricky (http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil). So it's better to be put outside the location block. However, doing that affects performance because all requests have to go through that if block.

It's better to use map directive (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule) to set the variable and then use that variable in the proxy directives. Performance is better (see how it works in the above link).

```
map $http_x_requested_with $nocache {
    default 0;
    XMLHttpRequest 1;
}

server {
    ...
    proxy_cache_bypass  $nocache;
    proxy_no_cache      $nocache;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this works for me:

```
if ($http_x_requested_with = XMLHttpRequest) {
    set $nocache 1;
}
```

Comment: Where you place this configuration? I mean server block or location